# change date format to local language

Tags: php, laravel, date, locale, date-format

I want to change date format in english language("Monday, 04 July 2020") to indonesia(Senin, 04 Juli 2020).
I change config/App.php

```
'locale' => 'id',
```

and add some code to Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
   public function boot()
    {
        config(['app.locale' => 'id']);
        Carbon::setLocale('id');
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    }
```

my model

```
 public function dateFormat()
    {
        return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->attributes['tanggal_acara'])
        ->formatLocalized("%A, %d %B %Y");
    }
```

and this my blade

```
{{ $event->dateFormat() }}
```

but the result still same "Monday, 04 July 2020"

anyone tell me what I've missed?

Comment: Make sure that the relevant locale is properly configured on the server level, PHP does not handle locale config internally and leverages the server's resources. Here is an example for Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server

Comment: I think July 4th 2020 is a Saturday, not a Monday! I get as result "Sabtu, 04 Juli 2020",

Comment: this problem already solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved
use this liblary
https://github.com/jenssegers/date

This date library extends Carbon with multi-language support. Methods such as format, diffForHumans, parse, createFromFormat and the new timespan, will now be translated based on your locale.

Answer (score 0):

Set the language in /app/config/app.php

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Jakarta',
'locale' => 'id',
'faker_locale' => 'id_ID',
```

// App\Providers\AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    config(['app.locale' => 'id']);
    Carbon::setLocale('id');
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');

}
```

Comment: add these setting App\Providers\AppServiceProvider



public function boot()
{
 config(['app.locale' => 'id']);
 Carbon::setLocale('id');
 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');

}

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `formatLocalized()`, You will need to call php's `setlocale()` like so

```
public function boot()
{
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'id_ID');
    config(['app.locale' => 'id']);
    Carbon::setLocale('id');
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
}
```

Also as per Sammitch's comment, you need to make sure the locale is configured on your server (on linux this can be checked using `locale -a` command in the console) as `setlocale()` will not work otherwise